# Calculate inside map in es6

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I need to calculate the total for a specific field inside map

```
 {agent.reviews.map((a, i) => {
       return (
          <p style={{fontSize: 15}} key={a.id}>Knowledge Rating: 
                 {a.local_knowledge_rating}</p>
       )
  })}
```

Returns

```
Knowledge Rating: 1

Knowledge Rating: 2
```

But I need to achieved is to get the total instead

```
 Knowledge Rating: 3
```

Any ideas?

```
       "users": [
        {
          "name": "someee",
           "reviews": [
           {
              "id": 1,

              "local_knowledge_rating": 1,
            },
            {
               "id": 2,

                "local_knowledge_rating": 2,
             }
         ],
         }
        ]
```

Comment: Correct me if im wrong, you want to display a sum of `local_knowledge_rating` field based on `agent.reviews` right? What about `a.id`? Since result `3` is not part of `agent.reviews`?

Comment: Please include a sample data of `agent.reviews` in your question

Comment: Isn't reduce a good tool for this? You keep aggregating the numbers in every call and return  the p tag on the last loop based on the index?

Comment: @ira: What about `id` that you're expecting to be rendered `<p style={{fontSize: 15}} key={a.id}>`?

Comment: @Isaac key is required by Reactjs when using map, its just a key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like below

Declare below method outside render and pass reviews array to it as param

The below approach will sum the rating for every user

```
   sumRating = reviews => {
        let total = 0;
          agent.reviews.forEach(a => {
               total+= a.local_knowledge_rating;
          });
     return total;
  }


        <p style={{fontSize: 15}}>Knowledge Rating:   {this.sumRating()}</p>
```

There are many other ways to implement the same. The above approach is one of them

Comment: reviews is just part of users object. And there are many users thats why I am using map to iterate each users and count the specific key in review

Comment: @ira Please check my updated answer. You must be doing map for each user so for every user the sum will be calculated

Answer (score 0):

you can try sumBy with lodash: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#sumBy

Answer (score 0):

```
renderKnowledgeRating() {
  const sum = agent.reviews.reduce(function(a, b) { return a. local_knowledge_rating + b. local_knowledge_rating; }, 0)

  return (
    <p style={{fontSize: 15}}>Knowledge Rating: {sum}</p>
  )
}

{this.renderKnowledgeRating()}
```

To enhance readability, extract the portion out to another method `renderKnowledgeRating`. and instead of using `map` which not really helping in your situation, handle the calculation differently, and return a single component

Answer (score -1):

As suggested try this:

```
function getSum(total, num) {
 return total + num.local_knowledge_rating;
}

{agent.reviews.map((a, i) => {
   return (
      <p style={{fontSize: 15}} key={a.id}>Knowledge Rating: 
             {a.reduce(getSum)}</p>
   )
})}
```

Comment: .map will return a new array based on caller. How many components will be rendered from your code?

Comment: it will print : Knowledge Rating: 3 based on input you have mentioned above. If you have more user put one more map outside reviews and you can generate as many user reviews.

Comment: a.local_knowledge_rating.reduce is not a function error

Comment: {agent.reviews.map((a, i) => {
   return (
      <p style={{fontSize: 15}} key={a.id}>Knowledge Rating: 
             {a.reduce(getSum)}</p>
   )
})}

function getSum(total, num) {
 return total + num.local_knowledge_rating;
}

Comment: `a.local_knowledge_rating` is a field, not an `array`, you can't call `reduce` on it

Comment: `a` is one of the element of `agent.reviews`, how can you `reduce` on it?

Comment: reviews is an array and you use reduce on array. Hope its clear now

Comment: the point is, you're calling `reduce` on `a.reduce`. `a` is not an array, `a` is a single element. (I'm not the downvoter, if that matters)

Comment: Actually you're using reduce on an array element and not on it, that's illegal.

Comment: Even if this worked (it doesn't), it would print `Knowledge rating: 3` two times instead of once. This answer is wrong in multiple ways.